# Constructing a pair of matchings with needed characteristics

Tags: graph-theory

I'm studying for a test in Graph Theory and I don't know how to prove that Union and intersection part of the following exercise:

Let $M$ and $N$ be matchings in a graph $G$ with $|M|>|N|$. Then there exist matchings $M'$ and $N'$ in $G$ such that $|M'|=|M|-1, |N'|=|N|+1, M' \cap N' = M \cap N$ and $M' \cup N'=M \cup N$.

What I have until now:
I know that as $|M| > |N|$ then $N$ is not a maximum matching, so there is an $N$-augmenting path and therefore there is an $N'$ such that $|N'| = |N|+1$. 
I think I can see $N= M'$ and $M=N'$ but I don't know how to prove it formally.

Let call $T$ to $G[M\Delta N]=M\cup N−M\cup N$ Which each vertex in $T$ has a degree either one or two. Also, any component of $T$ is either an even cycle or a path with edges alternately in $M$ and $N$, where at least one path have starting and ending in $M$ because of the condition $|M|> |N|$.

P.D. Some modifications of the question have been done according to the hints given by @LeenDroogendijk

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, for example, I know that as |M| > |N| then N is not a maximum matching, so there is an N-augmenting path and therefore there is an N' s.t. |N'| = |N|+1. 
I think I can see N= M' and M=N' but I don't know how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: consider the subgraph $H$ of $G$ induced by the edges of $M\cup N$.
Note that the edges that belong to $M\cap N$ are "isolated edges" in $H$.

What can you say about the degree of the vertices of $H$?

What do the connected components of this graph look like?

Now use the fact that $|M|>|N|$.

Comment: I can say that for all v in H, the deg (v) = 2.  
I know that $T=G [M \Delta N]= M \cup N - M \cap N $ Which each vertex in T has a degree either one or two. 
 Also, any component of T is either an even cycle or a path with edges alternately in M and N (starting and ending in M).
@LeenDroogendijk

Comment: Not quite. Every vertex in $H$ has degree at most $2$. Also the edges of a path do not need to start and end in $M$, but there must be at least one path for which this is true (why?).

Comment: Because |M| > |N|...

Comment: Yes, can you complete the proof now?

Comment: Not really, I don't know how to do the construction of the Union and Intersection.

Comment: On one path you find that has both end-edges in $M$ (or whose only edge is in $M$) you swap the edges between $M$ and $N$. Then you are done.